# How do I get SharedPreference object in FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences, fragmentstatepageradapter

I wanna add an integer dynamically in the getCount() method of custom pager adapter that obviously extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

```
return some integer value;
```

I have a counter saved in Shared Preference object and it gets updated with clicks on star images. I wanna return the updated counter value in the mentioned method, so I can generate that many swipe views but the problem is I unable to get Shared Preference object there. This is the only obstacle between my app and the play store, I've been developing it for like month or two. So please gimme suggestion on this issue I'm facing. Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int))

Set your `value` onPause() and onStop and read your `value` onResume and onCreate.

You need to set a final string which would be your SharedPreferences filename.

Get your value and increment

Writing:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_FINAL_STRING, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_value), newValue);
editor.commit();
```

Reading:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(YOUR_FINAL_STRING, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_value_default);
long value = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_value), defaultValue);
```

First read the value and set it to a variable in shared preferences.

Increment the same value onPause or onStop.

Comment: Does a class that extends Fragment state pager adapter have these callback methods?

Comment: In the first example on the [page](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) it is used inside a Fragment.

Comment: Man I'm unable to use activity()

Comment: remove `getActivity()` altogether or try `ActivityName.this.getSharedPreferences(...)`

Comment: @Override
     public int getCount() {
         SharedPreferences fav = Favourites.this.getSharedPreferences("Favourite_Couplets", 0);
         return int;
     }

Comment: Above code I tried in the getCount method. I'm getting some kinda warning that 'Favourites' isn't an enclosing class. I don't know what does that mean.

Comment: Is Favourites the name of the activity?

Try to declare a final string at the top instead of the one in'`("Favourite_Couplets", 0)`' and intead of '`0`', `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`.

Comment: Also by only doing that you are not getting or setting a value in sharedpreferences

Comment: Yes Favorites is the name of the activity. And 0 already means Context. MODE_PRIVATE

Comment: @Galeaetty Could you suggest something else? It's not working.

Comment: Sorry that's what worked for me, try `getDefaultSharedPreferences`,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252146/sharedpreferences-in-fragment / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031825/reading-sharedpreferences-data-in-fragment-within-fragmentactivity