# could not show a simple alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I've set an on click listener on a linear layout. Here's the code:

```
Context context = this;
  LinearLayout credit = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.credits_activity);
    credit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder creditDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            creditDialog.setTitle(R.string.credits_title)
                    .setMessage(R.string.credits_content)
                    .setNeutralButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog dialog = creditDialog.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Can anyone tell what's wrong?

Comment: Change  `AlertDialog.Builder creditDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());` to  `AlertDialog.Builder creditDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();`

Comment: why? any error? or crash ?

Comment: repplace getApplicationContext() with YourActivity.this

Comment: Getting error, saying activityName.this is not an enclosing class.

Comment: Yes it's crashing

Comment: kis maa ke lode ne isko downvote kiya hai?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using getapplicationcontext() in AlertDialog.builder(getapplicationcontext())

```
 LinearLayout credit = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.credits_activity);
        credit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder creditDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this);
                creditDialog.setTitle(R.string.credits_title)
                        .setMessage(R.string.credits_content)
                        .setNeutralButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        }).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but getting the error. Saying activityName is not an enclosing class. What do you think?

Comment: Sorry it was my fault. I have two activities with names 'MainActivity' and 'MainContent'. I was using the former one in the place of the latter one.

Comment: Could you also look at this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44051292/how-do-i-get-sharedpreference-object-in-fragmentstatepageradapter]

Answer (score 0):

In place of getApplicationContext() pass ActivityName.this